# Jquery JSON interation

Tags: jquery, json

I am grabbing a JSON response from AJAX request, the output is something like this

```
{

    "update":
        [{
            "selector":"#selectorname",
            "attribute":"value",
            "value":1
        }],
    "hide":[
        "#tohideselector1",
        "#tohideselector2",
        "#tohideselector3"
        ],
    "show":[
        "#toshowselector1",
        "#toshowselector2",
        "#toshowselector3"        
    ]
}
```

Now I need the array key to send them to their specific function, as each action can occur more than once. I need a function which in PHP would look like this

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    switch($key) {
        case "update":
              update(param1,param2,param3);
              break;
        case "hide":
              hide(param1);
              break;
        case "show":
              show(param1);
              break;  
    }    
}
```

If you have understood, what I am trying to say... What is the solution to this?

Comment: AJAX requests don't create JSON responses. If a request creates JSON, one would usually refer to it as a JSON message or JSON packet.

Comment: The PHP code I wrote is just an illustration of what I want in Jquery. So please remove all answers giving me PHP solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the jQuery each function, the js would be something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) { 
  if(key cond){
  }
  else if (key cond){
  }
  ...
  ...
  else {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this.  jQuery gives you a standard JavaScript object representing the JSON object.  What you want is trivial:

```
var key, value;

for (key in data) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, key)) {
        continue;
    }

    value = data[key];

    switch (key) {
        case 'update':
            // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks... for the solution. However I will stick the jquery's Solution

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, just decode the object and then you can access it. This isn't exact, you'll need to var_dump the decoded json and make some adjustments, but here's the basic idea:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["requestSent"]);
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    switch($key) {
        case "update":
              update($value[0]->selector,$value[0]->attribute,$value[0]->value);
              break;
        case "hide":
              /*pass params here*/
              break;
        case "show":
              /*pass params here*/
              break;  
    }    
}
```